# Create an index in azure search services failed

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I just follow this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-rest
and try to add an index in services but failed，I raise this request both in POSTMAN and .net console with http client.

My request as below:

```
POST https://[servicename].search.windows.net/indexes?api-version=[api-version]  
  Content-Type: application/json
  api-key: [admin key]


<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Is your search service name `ss-shh-projectname-dev`?

Comment: I just changed the project name instead,the real name is ss-shh-crowdknowledgef3-dev

Comment: Thanks. Can you edit your question and include the complete request?

Comment: I am interested in seeing the request body (basically your index definition).

Comment: I use the body in the official document, pretty the same one

Comment: So I tried the same and was able to create an index. I would request you to share your exact request body. I have a feeling that there might be an issue there only.

Comment: Can you check if the service fully created by checking the DNS entry with "nslookup [servicename].search.windows.net"?